# What is the Rails convention for input validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For verifying input parameters for the web API, what is the convention that Ruby on Rails follows?
Specifically, I am interested in checking if the "date" send by a client is in expected formats.
validate_timeliness GEM seems to be very popular in validating dates that go in the model. But it doesn't seem very useful in validating if the date read from the client in a request is well-formed.
How do I perform error checks on the dates and return errors, per Rails convention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails convention says: the controllers don't care about data. That's work for models.

Create a class for the form, perhaps on folder app/forms, convert to a model without table. Use Restfull actions over that form (new and create).

Can read how to at: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html